# how to create temporary data for web apps with javascript?

Tags: javascript, random, generator

I wanted to generate some random or more like "fake" data like complete name for my web app, i've seen faker.js but it seemed there's a little bit of drama from the maintainer. checked multiple options but they seem little bit complicated for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use foobar.js, you can rely on the random data from it but you can also put custom data.

installation

```sh
npm install foobar.js
```

check out its README file here https://www.npmjs.com/package/foobar.js

Comment: ok, this is the simplest way possible, something like 
e.g. `const generator = require('foobar.js'); let firstname = generator.firstName('male'); `